# iOS IBOutlet Items not being allocated

Tags: ios, iboutlet

I set up a bunch of IBOutlet items in my xib files, but then my program finds out later none of them are being allocated. Why is that?

Under what conditions the IBOutlet items are not allocated? Still scratching my head on this.

Is it memory low and it doesn't want to allocate?

This happened on a UIViewController. But if I switch a UIView it doesn't happen.

But I need a UIViewCOntroller.

Comment: I'll be damned. After the whole afternoon of trying, none of the Items being allocated suddenly, it's working again.Things being allocated!!  Compiler issue? could very well be...   hick up.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a mistake somewhere. Are you sure you've wired up the views in IB to their outlets? Are you sure you're retaining all of your outlet properties (or, if under ARC, they're strong properties)? Have you synthesized all the outlet properties?

Comment: not really, I also try to explicitly allocate them by calling UILabel alloc but no valid memory address allocated.   So it's the IBOutlet only.  Something not allowed to allocate